# IDA PRO - compare running process

Tags: ida, debugging, patch-reversing

I have a software which writes some data to specific location in memory depending on user choices.
Say i can have 2 choices, A & B.
I want to run IDA, set option A and save all the data, then run it again with option B and save and after that compare the 2.

Can i do this?

How?

Comment: The question is pretty vague: "I want to run IDA, set option A and save all the data". What does "save all the data" mean? If you're talking about something in a data section, you could manually save the data as a binary file and then do a binary diff after each. (You could even do this with an entire data section.) If you're talking about heap-allocated data, your life is going to be harder.  Nevertheless, the question really can't be answered until you be more specific about what the data is.

Answer (score 3):

What you are asking for is called ["Differential Debugging"](https://blog.zynamics.com/2010/01/19/binnavi-3-0-preview-improved-differential-debugging/). Take a look to [this tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20191016043447/https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/tutorials/replayer/trace_replayer.pdf) to see how to do so with IDA without requiring any kind of plugins, just built-in functionality.

Comment: The link you provided for IDA does not work anymore

Comment: I have updated to link to point to the PDF in the web archive.

Answer (score 1):

You may collect code coverage in both cases and then make a diff via ida plugin like [lighthouse](https://github.com/gaasedelen/lighthouse)

Comment: how do you collect the data for this plugin?

Comment: the way it's described at "Collecting Coverage" section at the main page.